# Frequency table with ddply function

Tags: r, algorithm

```
ID<-c("R1","R2","R2","R3","R3","R4","R4","R4","R4","R3","R3","R3","R3","R2","R2","R2","R5","R6")
event<-c("a","b","b","M","s","f","y","b","a","a","a","a","s","c","c","b","m","a")
df<-data.frame(ID,event)
```

How can I modify the below code to get this table. 2-How can i get the average of frequency for each element of frequency?for example: the average of frequency for a would be 1+3+1+1/4.

```
ddply(df,.(ID),summarise,N=sum(!is.na(ID)),frequency=length(event))

ID  N   Number-event-level  levels       frequency
R1  1      1                 a             a=1
R2  5      2                 b,c         b=3,c=2
R3  6      3                 M,a,s       M=1,a=3,s=2
R4  4      4                 f,y,b,a    f=1,y=1,b=1,a=1
R5  1      1                 m             m=1
R6  1      1                 a             a=1
```

Comment: Have you tried: `ftable( df )`

Comment: Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an answer for the first question:

```
ddply(df,.(ID),summarise,
      N=length(event),
      Number.event.level=length(unique(event)),
      levels=paste(sort(unique(event)),collapse=","),
      frequency=paste(paste(sort(unique(event)),table(event)[table(event)>0],sep="="),collapse=","))
#   ID N Number.event.level  levels       frequency
# 1 R1 1                  1       a             a=1
# 2 R2 5                  2     b,c         b=3,c=2
# 3 R3 6                  3   a,M,s     a=3,M=1,s=2
# 4 R4 4                  4 a,b,f,y a=1,b=1,f=1,y=1
# 5 R5 1                  1       m             m=1
# 6 R6 1                  1       a             a=1
```

For your second question, it seems like you want to get the average frequency when the frequency is greater than 0.  If that's the case, you can do this:

```
apply(table(df),2,function(x) mean(x[x>0]))
#   a   b   c   f   m   M   s   y 
# 1.5 2.0 2.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 2.0 1.0
```

**Update**

If you want to do that last part for each level of a third variable and you still want to use `ddply()` you could do the following:

```
df1 <- rbind(df,df)
df1$cat <- rep(c("a","b"),each=nrow(df))

ddply(df1,.(cat),function(y) apply(table(y),2,function(x) mean(x[x>0])))
#   cat   a b c f m M s y
# 1   a 1.5 2 2 1 1 1 2 1
# 2   b 1.5 2 2 1 1 1 2 1
```

Comment: Great, Thanks so much

Comment: I have another question. How can I modify your solution (second part) If I have, three categorical variables. I want to calculate the average of event (sum(event)/number of ids) for each levels of third variable. I mean, I want to calculate apply(table(df$ID, df$event),2,function(x) mean(x[x>0]))  for each level of third variable.

Comment: @ Sam Dickson, Thanks so much for your time and kindness. When I run this function on my data set, I got this error:                                                                    Error in list_to_dataframe(res, attr(.data, "split_labels"), .id, id_as_factor) : Results do not have equal lengths.  Any advice regarding fixing this issue?

Comment: The easiest solution would be to make `event` a factor: `df1$event <- as.factor(df1$event)`.

Comment: Great, Thanks so much